# WSO2 agent compilation error with Android Studio 2.1.3

Tags: android, wso2

I follow the instruction in Wiki (https://docs.wso2.com/display/EMM201/Creating+a+New+Android+APK+File) and compile the project with Android Studio 2.1.3. But it gives me the following error:

```
C:\shared\source\product-mdm\modules\mobile-agents\android\client\client\src\main\java\org\wso2\emm\agent\services\NetworkConnectedReceiver.java
Error:(42, 28) error: cannot find symbol method startServiceAsUser(Intent,UserHandle)
C:\shared\source\product-mdm\modules\mobile-agents\android\client\client\src\main\java\org\wso2\emm\agent\utils\CommonUtils.java
Error:(432, 11) error: cannot find symbol method startServiceAsUser(Intent,UserHandle)
Error:(445, 11) error: cannot find symbol method startServiceAsUser(Intent,UserHandle)
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
```

Any idea on how to resolve this?

Comment: I am having this issue as well.

Comment: Hope you are trying out this with WSO2 EMM 2.0.1.If that is the case did you clone the correct version? Because if you just cloned master branch it won't compatible with 2.0.1. Also, let us know java version and android version which you are trying out?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`startServiceAsUser` is a part of the framework internal APIs and this is not a public API. For compile this you need to use the android.jar which is built using the original [Android Open Source Project](https://source.android.com/) (AOSP)

This [repository](https://github.com/anggrayudi/android-hidden-api) contains the android.jar s with hidden APIs enabled for all the SDK versions. You can download the jar relevant to your SDK version and replace it with the local android.jar file which is usually located at /platforms/android- path and rebuild the agent.